# python setuptools depend on absolute path

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

We have a large git structure and inside that we wanted to create some python libraries, where some is referencing the other. Since we pull the git all at once we don't want setup tools reference each other via the VCS repository reference.

Currently what I was able to do was this:

```
from setuptools import setup
import setuptools.command.install
import pip._internal
import os

try:
    era_root = os.environ.get("ERA_ROOT")
    if not os.path.isdir(era_root):
        raise ValueError("ERA_ROOT must point to a valid directory")
except KeyError as k:
    raise KeyError("Please specify the ERA_ROOT environment variable")

protobufsDependency = "{}/Products/PythonLibs/Protobufs".format(
    era_root)


class my_install(setuptools.command.install.install):

    def run(self):
        pip._internal.main(['install', '-I', protobufsDependency])
        setuptools.command.install.install.run(self)


setup(name='replication_tools',
      version='1.0',
      packages=["FakeAgent", "EventGenerator"],
      cmdclass={"install": my_install},
      )
```

However this is problematic because if someone is installing this library with --user or some other params I would have to manually name them all in the pip._internal.main . So my question is is there some way I can reference with setuptools.setup the protobufsDependency directly as if it was a url package? 
Something like (as this doesnt work but something like that)

```
setup(name='replication_tools',
      version='1.0',
      packages=["FakeAgent", "EventGenerator"],
      install_requires=[
         protobufsDependency
      ]
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that I can use direct reference link

```
setup(name='replication_tools',
      version='1.0',
      packages=["FakeAgent", "EventGenerator"],
      install_requires=[
         "protobufs-generated @ file://C:/PathToMyLib"
      ]
     )
```